# How to replace branding resources( logos, background images) of react js app running inside the docker container

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx

I am new to react and docker so my question can be little naive. Please bear with me.

I have react js app running inside nginx and node as builder for nginx container. Now I want to suppot the branding in terms of replacing logos, background images etc without any code changes. So if there is any change in the logo/any background image, I should be able to do it by replacing the resources and may be restart the container.

What is it that I have to do inside a container or any better solution to address the problem?

I am using node container to build the react app and using this as builder while running the nginx container.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy resources from docker host to docker container using [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) command:

For example, to override  logo use: `docker cp logo.jpeg container_id:[path_to_logo_inside_the_container]`